# How to get value in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

### How to get value in method asynchronous

```
public void getGetDataByUrl(String url) {
            MainActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  getDataVebview(url);
                }
            });
}
```

### boolean isPageMediaFinished = false;

```
 @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    public void getDataVebview(String url) {
        _webView = new WebView(MainActivity.getInstance());
        _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebAppInterface webAppInterface = new WebAppInterface(MainActivity.getInstance());
        _webView.addJavascriptInterface(webAppInterface, Constant.WEBAPP_JSI);
        isPageMediaFinished = false;
        _webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (isPageMediaFinished){
                    return;
                }

                isPageMediaFinished = true;

                    _webView.evaluateJavascript(Constant.GET_JSI_URL, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                            if(value != null) {
                 //How to get data value in method setGetData
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        _webView.loadUrl(url);
```

### }

How to get "value" of method  getDataVebview in method getGetDataByUrl ??

Comment: Use asyncTask.. better learn about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example